# Syntax to use combination of two hash algorithm

Tags: python

I would like to know how to write in a single line the combination of two hash algorithms in Python. I want to use MD5 and sha256 in one line. Here is my function:

```
def calcHash(self):
    block_string = json.dumps({"nonce":self.nonce, "tstamp":self.tstamp, "output":self.output, "prevhash":self.prevhash}, sort_keys=True).encode()
    return hashlib.sha256(block_string).hexdigest()
```

I tried return `md5.hashlib(hashlib.sha256(block_string).hexdigest())` but it doesn't work.
Can someone help?

Comment: does it return an error? if so, what is it?

Comment: Doesn't work how? Doesn't run? Produces the wrong result?

Comment: Are you expecting to `md5` the hex or binary representation of `sha256`?

Comment: `md5.hashlib`? Shouldn't that be `hashlib.md5`?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could just be that `.hexdigest()` produces a string, not a bytes, so you need to encode it again

```py
>>> import hashlib, json
>>> j = json.dumps({"foo":"bar","baz":2022})
>>> hashlib.sha256(j.encode()).hexdigest()
'44ce0f46288befab7f32e9acd68d36b2a9997e801fb129422ddc35610323c627'
>>> hashlib.md5(hashlib.sha256(j.encode()).hexdigest().encode()).hexdigest()
'f7c6be48b7d34bcd278257dd73038f67'
```

Alternatively, you could directly use `.digest()` to get bytes from the hash, rather than intermediately converting it to a hex string (though note the output is different)

```py
>>> hashlib.md5(hashlib.sha256(j.encode()).digest()).hexdigest()
'12ac82f5a1c0cb3751619f6d0ae0c2ee'
```

If you have a great many algorithms in some order, you may find [`.new()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.new) useful to iteratively produce a result from some list of hashes.

**BEWARE**
[md5 is broken from a security perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and I cannot recommend using it unless it's a required input to a legacy system!